# Upload Progress Info for Web Client Async upload not working c#

Tags: c#, upload, webclient

I am using the following code to start my asynchronous upload.

```
 uploadWebClient = new WebClient();
 uploadWebClient.UploadProgressChanged += UploadWebClient_UploadProgressChanged;
 uploadWebClient.UploadFileCompleted += UploadWebClient_UploadFileCompleted;

 try
 {
    uploadWebClient.UploadFileAsync(new Uri("https://uploadserver.ballpark.altemista.cloud/upload?token=nttdata2021encrypted22331124"), outputFile);
 }
 catch (WebException e)
 {
    mainWindow.WriteLine("ERROR: Upload Failed!\n" + e.Response.ToString());
 }
```

This is the method to set the progress info

```
 private void UploadWebClient_UploadProgressChanged(object sender, UploadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
 {
     Debug.WriteLine("Upload {0}% complete. Uploaded {1}/{2} MB", e.ProgressPercentage, e.BytesSent, e.TotalBytesToSend);
 }
```

This is the output I am getting:

```
Upload 0% complete. Uploaded 48898216/-1 MB
```

It's always 0% which I learned is common when working with progress info.
The Problem is that I can't use Total Bytes to send as it is always -1.

Why is this?

Comment: maybe you need to await since it async?

Comment: As I understand, these Events only get fired when using async upload. They are supposed to run alongside the upload. So I don´t think thats the case

Comment: I worked around the issue by getting new FileInformation(outputFile).Length and calculating Progress myself.